# Chaining Pair of numbers

Tags: c#

I've got a list of pair of numbers:

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> pairs = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

a. pairs.Add(Tuple.Create<int, int>(1, 2));
b. pairs.Add(Tuple.Create<int, int>(3, 4));
c. pairs.Add(Tuple.Create<int, int>(3, 5));
d. pairs.Add(Tuple.Create<int, int>(5, 6));
e. pairs.Add(Tuple.Create<int, int>(10, 11));
f. pairs.Add(Tuple.Create<int, int>(2, 3));
```

I'd like to join them in another List or Dictionary grouping them if they are related.

In the example above, the result step by step should be:

a. `result[0] = {1, 2}`
b. `result[0] = {1, 2} result[1] = {3, 4}`
c. `result[0] = {1, 2} result[1] = {3, 4, 5}` (5 was added to [1] since 3 was there)
d. `result[0] = {1, 2} result[1] = {3, 4, 5, 6}` (6 was added to [1] since 5 was there)
e. `result[0] = {1, 2} result[1] = {3, 4, 5, 6} result[2] { 10, 11 }`
f. `result[0] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} result[2] { 10, 11 }` (3 was added to [0] since 2 was there, which made [1] merge with [0] since 3 was in [1])

end result: `result[0] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} result[2] { 10, 11 }`

Is there any easy way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Why those `a.   b.  c.`? That obfuscates the code. Remove it and use the code-format button

Comment: this question really isn't very clear.

Comment: "Is there any easy way to do this? " did you already have a solution where you tried it the hard way?

Comment: I think I understand. So if the next pair was `11,6`, that would merge the two results and leave you with one result of `1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11`, correct?

Comment: Step f is quite confusing. What is the trigger for merging result[0] with result[1]? Is end of the feed a trigger? If not, why it wasn't merged in previous step? Are you simply looking your result list to contain continuous ranges? Will numbers in your input tuples always be sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my first try at it. Run it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mqq5dQ

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Tuple<int, int>> pairs = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        pairs.Add(Tuple.Create<int, int>(1, 2));
        pairs.Add(Tuple.Create<int, int>(3, 4));
        pairs.Add(Tuple.Create<int, int>(3, 5));
        pairs.Add(Tuple.Create<int, int>(5, 6));
        pairs.Add(Tuple.Create<int, int>(10, 11));
        pairs.Add(Tuple.Create<int, int>(2, 3));

        var results = new List<List<int>>();
        foreach(var pair in pairs)
        {
            var found = false;
            foreach(var result in results)
            {
                var item1Found = result.Contains(pair.Item1);
                var item2Found = result.Contains(pair.Item2);

                if(item1Found && item2Found){
                    found = true;
                    break;  
                }

                if(item1Found && !item2Found){
                    AddNum(result, results, pair.Item1, pair.Item2);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
                if(item2Found && !item1Found){
                    AddNum(result, results, pair.Item2, pair.Item1);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!found){
                results.Add(new List<int> { pair.Item1, pair.Item2 });
            }
        }
        foreach(var result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result.OrderBy(i => i).ToArray()));
        }
    }

    public static void AddNum(List<int> result, List<List<int>> results, int existing, int newnum)
    {
        result.Add(newnum);
        foreach(var otherresult in results){
            if(otherresult != result){
                if(otherresult.Contains(newnum)){
                    var newresult = result.Concat(otherresult).Distinct().ToArray();
                    result.Clear();
                    result.AddRange(newresult);
                    results.Remove(otherresult);
                    break;  
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of a list named `PairList` which has a `Add` method that accepts a Tuple and does what you want.

Note: I took the liberty to change `List<Tuple<int,int>>` to `List<List<int>>` because your 'pairs' may contain multiple numbers when joined.

Example usage:

```
PairList pairs = new PairList();

pairs.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 2));
pairs.Add(Tuple.Create(3, 4));
pairs.Add(Tuple.Create(3, 5));
pairs.Add(Tuple.Create(5, 6));
pairs.Add(Tuple.Create(10, 11));
pairs.Add(Tuple.Create(2, 3));

foreach(List<int> list in pairs) {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", list));
}
// Output:
// 1,2,3,4,5,6
// 10,11
```

Implementation:

```
public class PairList : List<List<int>>
{
    public void Add(Tuple<int, int> pair)
    {
        // convert from Tuple<int, int> to List<int>
        List<int> newList = new List<int>() { pair.Item1, pair.Item2 };
        newList = newList.OrderBy(i => i).ToList(); // sort

        // tries to join the new list to any of the existing lists
        List<int> joinedList = null;
        for(int i = Count-1; i>=0; --i) {
            if(TryJoin(newList, this[i], out joinedList)) {
                this[i] = joinedList;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(joinedList == null) {
            // the new list was not joined with any of the existing lists
            // so just add it
            Add(newList);
            return;
        }

        // the new list was joined with one of the existing lists
        // so compare all lists with each other and check if they can be joined
        // repeat until no list was joined
        do {
            joinedList = null;
            for(int i = Count-1; i>=0; --i) {
                for(int j = Count-1; j>=0; --j) {
                    if(i == j) continue;

                    if(TryJoin(this[i], this[j], out joinedList)) {
                        this[i] = joinedList;
                        this.RemoveAt(j);
                        // break out of both for loops
                        i = -1;
                        j = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        } while(joinedList != null);
    }

    private bool TryJoin(List<int> list1, List<int> list2, out List<int> joinedList)
    {
        int low1 = list1[0];
        int low2 = list2[0];
        int high2 = list2.Last();

        // I'm assuming these two conditions are the only valid ones to join
        if(low1 == low2 || low1 == high2){
            joinedList = new List<int>(list1);
            joinedList.AddRange(list2);
            joinedList = joinedList.Distinct().OrderBy(j => j).ToList();
            return true;
        }
        joinedList = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer fails if you add `11,3` as the next pair. It add it as a new result instead of merging the two existing.

Comment: @adam0101 Well, he never specified what happens when you try to add a pair that is already inside the scope, or did he? :) This implementation works in situations as the specified example, which is all that was provided at this time.

Answer (score 0):

This produces the output that you specified - but it's not going to be very efficient with large data sets!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var pairs = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
            {
                Tuple.Create(1, 2),
                Tuple.Create(3, 4),
                Tuple.Create(3, 5),
                Tuple.Create(5, 6),
                Tuple.Create(10, 11),
                Tuple.Create(2, 3),
            };

            var groups = new List<List<int>>();

            foreach (var pair in pairs)
            {
                var g1 = groups.Select((g, i) => (g, i)).FirstOrDefault(h => h.g.Contains(pair.Item1));
                var g2 = groups.Select((g, i) => (g, i)).FirstOrDefault(h => h.g.Contains(pair.Item2));

                if (g1.g == null && g2.g == null)
                {
                    groups.Add(new List<int>{ pair.Item1, pair.Item2 });
                }
                else if (ReferenceEquals(g1.g, g2.g)) // Pair already in a single group.
                {
                    // Do nothing.
                }
                else if (g1.g != null && g2.g != null) // Pair appears in two different groups, so join them.
                {
                    g1.g.AddRange(g2.g);
                    g1.g = g1.g.Distinct().ToList();
                    groups.RemoveAt(g2.i);
                }
                else if (g1.g != null) // First of pair appears in g1, so add second of pair.
                {
                    g1.g.Add(pair.Item2);
                }
                else // Second of pair appears in g2, so add first of pair.
                {
                    g2.g.Add(pair.Item1);
                }
            }

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", group));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody, that was fast... 
I previously came up with this solution, I thought there was a simplier solution. Some of the code you people posted are far better so I'm going to take them. Thanks!

```
    Dict<string, List<int>> chains = new Dict<string, List<int>>();

    List<Tuple<int, int>> pairs = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
    pairs.Add(Tuple.Create<int, int>(1, 2));
    pairs.Add(Tuple.Create<int, int>(3, 4));
    pairs.Add(Tuple.Create<int, int>(3, 5));
    pairs.Add(Tuple.Create<int, int>(5, 6));
    pairs.Add(Tuple.Create<int, int>(10, 11));
    pairs.Add(Tuple.Create<int, int>(2, 3));

    foreach (Tuple<int, int> pair in pairs)
    {
        string foundChainId    = String.Empty;
        string chainIdToRemove = String.Empty;

        foreach (string chainId in chains.Keys)
        {
            List<int> bitList = chains[chainId];
            bool hasPair1 = bitList.Contains(pair.Item1);
            bool hasPair2 = bitList.Contains(pair.Item2);
            if (hasPair1 || hasPair2)
            {
                foundChainId = chainId;

                if (hasPair1 != hasPair2) //One value was added
                {
                    int value = (!hasPair1 ? pair.Item1 : pair.Item2);
                    foreach (string chainMergeId in chains.Keys)
                    {
                        if (chains[chainMergeId].Contains(value))
                        {
                            chainIdToRemove = chainMergeId;
                            bitList.AddRange(chains[chainMergeId]);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (chainIdToRemove == String.Empty) //If there's no merge, add the new one value
                        bitList.Add(value);
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        if (chainIdToRemove != String.Empty)
            chains.Remove(chainIdToRemove);

        if (foundChainId == String.Empty)
        {
            foundChainId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            chains.Add(foundChainId, new List<int>());
            chains[foundChainId].Add(pair.Item1);
            chains[foundChainId].Add(pair.Item2);
        }
    }
```